# Client.abort is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I am getting below error while run test cases by using jest with react testing library

```
import React from 'react';
import { render} from '@testing-library/react';
import Somecomponent from './Somecomponent';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

describe('<Somecomponent /> spec', () => {
  it('renders the component', () => {
    const container = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Somecomponent />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Actual Result:

Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: client.abort is not a function

  at XMLHttpRequest.abort (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:379:16)
  at Object.abort (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:425:13)
  at RequestManager.close (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:133:21)
  at Window.close (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:513:29)
```

Comment: Can you add the code you want to test and the unit test code

Comment: Getting the same error, any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party, but I found my solution [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2139#issuecomment-1225261878) (in my case the error also occurred in Angular application). Adding the `HttpClientTestingModule` ensures it's not doing actual http requests in test cases.